# How to output foreign key data in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have 3 table in my database, which is:

1. transaction
2. books
3. users

transaction table has 3 column, which is :

1. id
2. user_id(ForeignKey from users)
3. book_id(ForeignKey from books)

right now im stuck in the state where i only able to output (select * from transaction where user_id => user()->id)

I'm terribly sorry, its really hard to put it into words. ill try again.

i wanted to echo all the rows from transaction table, but the output its not like what i expected. the output is 1 1, 0 1, 1 2 (its from user_id and book_id. and comma separate each row). what i expected is when i echo user_id, it will output all column from users table and when i echo book_id it will echo all column from books table. i read something on internet that to connect table we use foreign key. but i still do not know how the system work. i hope it is understandable

Comment: Can you rephrase your question: _"right now im stuck in the state where i only able to output (select * from transaction where user_id => user()->id)"_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_id = user()->id;

SELECT 
  t.*, u.* 
FROM
  transactions t, users u 
WHERE 
  t.user_id = u.user_id AND 
  t.user_id = $user_id
```

Is this what you were looking for?